# How to get parent POJO class field value using streams

Tags: java-8, stream

I have two classes - `Student` and `StudentDetails`.

My goal is to get data in the form of `Map <studentName,Map<subjectName, subjectNo>>`.

When using streams, not able to fetch data of parent class(Student).

```
public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private Map<String, Long> studentDetails;

    public Map<String, Long> getStudentDetails() {
        return studentDetails;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
}

class StudentDetails {

    private String subjectName;
    private String subjectNo;

    public String getFSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public String getSubjectNo() {
        return subjectNo;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Student> student = null;

        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> sts = student.stream()
        .map(st -> st.getStudentDetails().values())
        .flatMap(st -> st.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStudentName,
                Collectors.toMap(StudentDetails :: getFatherName, StudentDetails:: getRollNo )));
    }
}
```

> Error : The type Student does not define getStudentName(T) that is applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "lost" your Student while doing:

```
.map(st -> st.getStudentDetails().values())
.flatMap(st -> st.stream()) // this is a Stream<StudentDetails> now
```

Thus if you need it just map it:

```
.flatMap(st -> st.getStudentDetails()
                 .values()
                 .stream()
                 .map(sd -> new SimpleEntry<>(st, sd)))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
       en -> en.getKey().getStudentName(),
       Collectors.toMap(
            en -> en.getValue().getFartherName(),
            en -> en.getValue().getRollNo()
       )
))
```

This can be done without Streams too; you could try to look at `Map::compute`